# Transaction Management in Google Bigquery

Tags: google-bigquery

This issue is regarding transaction management in BigQuery. I am trying to insert into multiple tables from my code. However since there is an implicit commit after each statement, there is no way for me to rollback from the first table if the insert into the subsequent tables fail. I have situations where tables are functionally related and we need to have data in all them to make logical sense. Orphan records in some tables lead to data integrity issues. Does anyone have a solution?

Answer (score 3):

This is an opinion-based answer, but it doesn't sound like BigQuery is the right database for your purpose.  BQ is perfect for Analytics/DataScience scenarios where analyzing data "after the fact" is the point, and transactional integrity is not a product requirement.

If you are set on using BQ in this manner, consider keeping your original/source table, and create your 'insert' records into a new table(s), then process/query both sources into a new table to work with. This is a pattern that will preserve your transactions and you can recreate/resolve/remove any transactions.

Comment: Thanks i like the 2nd option though it might be a tad costly. On your opinion on the database itself, would you recommend an alternate DB altogether? And if yes what would it be? My high level requirement is to be able to receive data in csv(structure is not exactly known but high volumes). I would then process it using some computational logic(the logic itself may be in java or python) and then persist the output back. I would then need to report out of the persisted results.

Answer (score 3):

The best way to avoid such scenario in BigQuery is to have your data denormalized

BigQuery performs best when your data is denormalized. Rather than preserving a relational schema such as a star or snowflake schema, you can improve performance by denormalizing your data and taking advantage of nested and repeated fields. Nested and repeated fields can maintain relationships without the performance impact of preserving a relational (normalized) schema.

The storage savings from normalized data are less of a concern in modern systems. Increases in storage costs are worth the performance gains from denormalizing data. Joins require data coordination (communication bandwidth). Denormalization localizes the data to individual slots so execution can be done in parallel.

If you need to maintain relationships while denormalizing your data, use nested and repeated fields instead of completely flattening your data. When relational data is completely flattened, network communication (shuffling) can negatively impact query performance.

For example, denormalizing an orders schema without using nested and repeated fields may require you to group by a field like order_id (when there is a one-to-many relationship). Because of the shuffling involved, grouping the data is less performant than denormalizing the data using nested and repeated fields.

See more at [Denormalize data whenever possible](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/best-practices-performance-input#denormalize_data_whenever_possible)

Comment: Thanks, i get the point around denormalizing the data. Let me look into it.

Answer (score 3):

[BigQuery supports multi-statement transactions](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/transactions) inside scripts. A multi-statement transaction lets you perform [SELECT, DML operations some DDL operations on Temporary tables and functions](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/transactions#statements_supported_in_transactions), such as inserting or deleting rows, on one or more tables, and either commit or roll back the changes atomically.

Uses for multi-statement transactions include:

- Performing DML mutations on multiple tables as a single transaction. The tables can span multiple datasets or projects.
- Performing mutations on a single table in several stages, based on intermediate computations.

```
BEGIN TRANSACTION;

-- Create a temporary table that holds new arrivals from 'warehouse #1'.
CREATE TEMP TABLE tmp
  AS SELECT * FROM mydataset.NewArrivals WHERE warehouse = 'warehouse #1';

-- Delete the matching records from the NewArravals table.
DELETE mydataset.NewArrivals WHERE warehouse = 'warehouse #1';

-- Merge the records from the temporary table into the Inventory table.
MERGE mydataset.Inventory AS I
USING tmp AS T
ON I.product = T.product
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
 INSERT(product, quantity, supply_constrained)
 VALUES(product, quantity, false)
WHEN MATCHED THEN
 UPDATE SET quantity = I.quantity + T.quantity;

-- Drop the temporary table and commit the transaction.
DROP TABLE tmp;

COMMIT TRANSACTION;
```

Answer (score 2):

The short answer is: you can't perform transaction management.

BigQuery is a datawarehouse designed for analytics. It's not intended as a transactional relational database. As said before, denormalizing increases the performance and the processing time of your data.

If you want this feature, you can use Cloud SQL database (MySQL or PostgreSQL) and perform your transactional load there. Then, you can query Cloud SQL database with BigQuery thanks to the [federated table feature](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/cloud-sql-federated-queries). You can do a copy into BigQuery if you want by performing an insert-select statement (be careful your are [limited to 1000 DML statements](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/quotas#table_limits) per days), always be thinking about denormalization and performance.

PS: Cloud SQL Microsoft SQL server is not yet supported as federated table feature.

Comment: further info: Batch/DML limits are not streaming related limits (these are distinct limits/operations), very important for the strategic infrastructure and ETL setup

Comment: Things are going to change !! My last year answer won't be true in 1 year!! Stay tuned